# The first 9 days of the month as a string

Tags: datetime

Is there a way to show the first 9 days of the month as 01, 02, 03 etc. \the\day prints 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: I think `scrdate` can do that with ease. Can you show us some code so we know how you want to use the date (and where).

Comment: Using `\the\day` will always use 1, 2 and so on, because `\the` is a primitive command that can't be modified. In what situation do you want this “two digit form” to be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  \ifnum\day<10 0\fi
  \the\day
```

Comment: David, I think it should be \ifnum\day<10 0\the\day\fi

Comment: @Reza that would make no output if the day is over 10. The code shown always uses 2 digits for the day.

Comment: David, you are right.